# Пользователь после авторизации на сайте имеет доступ только к своим файлам

Tags: python, django, auth, файлы, permissions

Подскажите как в Django разрешить авторизованному пользователю скачивать определённые(предназначенные для него) файлы? Чтобы по этой ссылке не получилось скачать файл в другом браузере или компьютере. И другой авторизованный пользователь мог скачивать только свои файлы, а не чужие.

Нашёл два решения: `django-downloadview` и `django-sendfile`. Так же можно использовать `HttpResponse`.

Как я понял это возможно использовать при маленьких файлах. Пример:

```
def download(request):
    my_data = 'some xls file'
    response = HttpResponse(my_data, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.xls'
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В django-sendfile можно использовать разные бекенды, отвечающие за передачу самого файла.

Бекенды sendfile.backends.development и sendfile.backends.simple возвращают файл средствами Django, и вся логика передачи файла идет через python и Django.

Другие бекенды используют различные механизмы, которые передают веб-серверу (apache, nginx, lighthttpd) инструкцию с информацией какой файл необходимо передать. В этом случае Django формирует специальный ответ с заголовком, который содержит путь к файлу и который понимает веб-сервер, X-Sendfile, Location или X-Accept-Redirect. Но такой способ требует, чтобы веб-сервер поддерживал какой-нибудь из вышеуказанных заголовков. В таком случае вся нагрузка по передаче файла ложится на плечи веб-сервера, а не Django, и можно использовать такой способ в production.